# Unable to check for required field dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

The `required` attribute of one of my input elements depends on `checked` state of one of the checkboxes. I'm unable to fire HTML5's required field error by dynamically setting `required` attribute on that field.

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
<input type="checkbox" name="immediate" id="immediate" onchange="setRequired(this.checked)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   function setRequired(checked)
   {
        var date = document.getElementById("date");
        if(checked) {
            date.required = false;
        }
        else
            date.required = true;

   }
</script>
```

When I run the form, I do not see HTML5 validation on date input.

Comment: `date.required = true` and `date.setAttribute('required','true')` are 2 different things. Give the `setAttribute` method a crack. There's a difference between a javascript member variable and an html attribute. For some elements, they're 100% equivalent. For others, the situation is a little less rosy.

Comment: `date.required = true` is setting `required` attribute on the input just like other fields on the form. Let me give `.setAttribute` a go.

Comment: Try less code: `document.getElementById("date").setAttribute('required', checked)`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - or more accurately, `....., !checked);` - it's  only required if the checkbox is unchecked. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" />
<input type="checkbox" name="immediate" id="immediate" onchange="setRequired(this.checked)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function setRequired(checked)
   {
  var date = document.getElementById("date");
            console.log(checked);
    if(checked) {

        date.setAttribute("required",false);
    }
    else {
        date.setAttribute("required",true);
    }
    console.log(date);
```

}

CONSOLE log will help you check the element changes

http://plnkr.co/edit/xFEJchgAqX5g9u2q6iWT?p=preview